# How do I deserialize a JSON object in Vb.net using Json.net?

Tags: json, vb.net

How do I deserialize a JSON object in Vb.net using Json.net? I saw from the documentation how to do simple conversions like strings and one array using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`. But I don't know how to deserialize something like this. I also checked the documentation for JSON.net but all the examples are in C# not vb.net.

```
"Sizes": [
   "Small",
  "Medium",
   "Large"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean **DEserialize**, which means take a JSON string and convert it into an object instance.

First you need a vb.net class to "receive" the JSON property values, such as "Sizes" that you have above. Then you pass this class to an instance of JavaScriptSerializer and you call method DeserializeObject.

In your example above, you have a JSON string array as value of "Sizes". You can deserialize the values into a Dictionary(Of String, Object) like this:

```
    Dim sizesStr = "{""Sizes"": [""Small"",""Medium"",""Large""]}"
    Dim jsSerializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim deSerialized = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(sizesStr)
    Dim sizes As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = CType(deSerialized, Dictionary(Of String, Object))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this template to convert to most types of objects

```
Dim obj as Object = Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of Object)(json)
```

I have always built a class to deserialize the json object into when the json becomes larger.